# I'm trying to get a fullscreen toggle button working in C# code with Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, toggle, fullscreen, fullscreenchange

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Fullscreentoggle : MonoBehaviour
{
    public void SetFullscreen (bool isFullscreen)
    {
        Screen.fullScreen = isFullscreen;
    }
}
```

Doesn't work, still don't know why. If someone can send a working script for this it would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

**Suggestions:**

I believe you should change the fullScreenMode as well to what ever you prefer.

```
Screen.fullScreen = isFullscreen;
Screen.fullScreenMode = FullScreenMode.FullScreenWindow;
```

Hope it works... Happy coding :)

Comment: == won't do much in this case. Assign with a single "=".

Comment: @MaxPlay oh sorry my typo..... I didn't mean to say that but yeah a single "=" should be used

Comment: anyways just edited and fixed my typo

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out though < 3